# Add/Remove dropdown Item Dynamically using Jquery

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc

I am working in a application in MVC. My requirement on selecting an item that item should be append to list item and the selcetd dropndown value should be removed.Till here I have achieved my requirement.
Next step when I remove any selected item from list that value should append again to dropdown.
Here is my code-

```
@Html.DropDownList("RateType", new List<SelectListItem>()
                                      {
                                          new SelectListItem(){ Text= "Hour", Value = "1"},
                                          new SelectListItem(){ Text= "Day", Value = "2"},
                                          new SelectListItem(){ Text= "Week", Value = "3"},
                                          new SelectListItem(){ Text= "Project", Value = "4"}
                                         }, "-Select-", new { @class = "form-control", id = "ddltype" })
```

In Jquery

```
 $("#addItem").click(function () {
        var selectedValue = document.getElementById('ddltype');
        var selectedText = selectedValue.options[selectedValue.selectedIndex].innerHTML;
        var desireMax = parseFloat(document.getElementById('maxRatevalue').value);
        var desireMin = parseFloat(document.getElementById('minRatevalue').value);
        var index = $('#ddltype').get(0).selectedIndex;
        $('#ddltype option:eq(' + index + ')').remove();
        $("ul").append("<li>" + "Type: " + selectedText + " High: " + desireMax + " Low: " + desireMin +" <a href='javascript:void(0);' class='remove'>X</a></li>");
    });
    $(document).on("click", "a.remove", function () {
        $(this).parent().remove();
    });
```

So how can I append item to dropdown again at same position.
Also I want to know how can I bind Id(say dropdown id) to list item dynamically?

Comment: In which event you want to add value to the dropdown

Comment: On cross button click I want item back to drop down.(In the last line of code i have mentioned)

Answer (score 0):

You can use jquery `Append` method. try the below code.

```
 $("#ddltype").eq(2).before($("<option></option>").val("").text("Select"));
```

specify the index you want the new option to add and also you can use [`.after()`](http://api.jquery.com/after) to insert the object.  (See also [`.insertBefore()`](http://api.jquery.com/insertBefore), [`.insertAfter()`](http://api.jquery.com/insertAfter))